# React.js Updating UI after removing a row form a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, I'm have a react component that generates a list. The list has a delete button generated with it, bound to an event handler. When the button is clicked I pass in the id of the row to be removed and then removed it. The part i'm struggling with is how to update the list once the row has been removed from it?

Whats the best practice react way of doing this ? I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/gLg02kpa/5/), but sadly it's not rendering my list.

Thanks for the help

```
var clickHandler = function(ev){
    var idx = ev.dispatchMarker.split('$')[1];
    data.splice( idx, 1 ); ///remove the row
    //how to update the ui?
};
```

Comment: As explained in the [Facebook tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state): 

"__... props are immutable: they are passed from the parent and are "owned" by the parent. To implement interactions, we introduce mutable state to the component.__"

So you have to use **state** and not **props** when you have a component with mutable state, like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in comments, use `state` instead of `props`.

But the direct answer to the question is to use: `this.forceUpdate();`